# Calendar Content Query on 3 lines

Tags: jquery, 2016, css, content-query-web-part

I have a design requirement based on a custom design created by a UX team to show the 3 most recent calendar entries on 3 separate div elements on a SharePoint 2016 Site Page.  Each should only pull one entry using a content query.

I need to show the event name on line 1, the event location on line 2, the event time on line 3.  I would like to stay completely client side if possible.  I attempted to use jQuery to add a line break after each instance of a character, such as the colon (:)

I tried using the replace method but it repeats the first entry in each div.  I then tried the following for each nth-of-type to no avail.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.item a:nth-of-type(1)").html($("div.item a:nth-of- 
   type(1)").html().replace(/:/g, "<br />Location:"));
    });
```

It continues to repeat the first event on each div instead of showing the other two events. Is this even possible or do I need to create a new XSL?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is valid justification in your unspecified backstory of why you are reformatting with jQuery instead of using the native XSL in the Content Query:

You should use the jQuery `.each()` ([see jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)) method to perform an operation on each selected item.  Each instance call of the loop makes the `this` keyword a reference to the currently selected html element.   So, your code would look something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.item a").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/:/g, "<br />Location:"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.  Add the . before each and it works perfectly. Much appreciated!

Comment: Lol, added my missing `.` to the answer.